# Globalleaks: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound A database result was required but none was found

Tags: sqlalchemy

Sometimes I get this mails from globalleaks but i can't found any problem.

has someone the same problems?

We update the always to the newest versions

i think it's an error while requesting some entries which were deleted after the period

here the error message:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound A database result was required but none was found.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1416, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 491, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/handlers/rtip.py", line 713, in get
tip, crypto_tip_prv_key = yield get_rtip(self.request.tid, self.current_user.user_id, tip_id, self.request.language)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 250, in inContext
result = inContext.theWork()

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 266, in <lambda>
inContext.theWork = lambda: context.call(ctx, func, *args, **kw)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
return func(args,*kw)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/orm.py", line 140, in _wrap
result = function(session, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/handlers/rtip.py", line 382, in get_rtip
return db_get_rtip(session, tid, user_id, rtip_id, language)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/handlers/rtip.py", line 360, in db_get_rtip
rtip, itip = db_access_rtip(session, tid, user_id, rtip_id)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/handlers/rtip.py", line 214, in db_access_rtip
models.InternalTip.tid == tid))

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/orm.py", line 96, in db_get
return db_query(session, selector, filter).one()

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3046, in one
raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bot trying to hit your globaleaks instance via its Onion address (via TOR). You can usually safely ignore these. I get them too once in a while.

If you look at your globaleaks.log log file, you will may something like this:

```
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] [E] Exception while running OnionService
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/services/service.py", line 25, in run
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-]     yield self.operation()
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] [E] Unhandled exception raised:
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] [E] twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/globaleaks/services/service.py", line 25, in run\n    yield self.operation()\n\ntwisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.\n
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] Stopping factory <Site object at 0x1234deadbeef>
2021-03-03 19:13:44+0000 [-] Server Shut Down.
```

Ideally this shouldn't trigger an email to site admins as it's just noise, but currently it does.